# Pipe command Find + Grep + Xargs + Tar (extract)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, debian

I don't understand why this bash code not working.

```
find -type f | grep file_ | xargs -0 -I file tar -zxf file --directory /tmp
```

I have this error:

```
tar (child): ./file_ok.tar.gz\n : open 
impossible: No file or folder of this type
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: 
exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Comment: I added my error

Comment: `find` has a built in search feature, which is why it's called "find" so the grep here is superfluous. `find` can also send what it finds to another program natively so the pipe to `xargs` is also superfluous.  Something like `find -type f -name "*file_*" -exec tar -zxf {} --directory /tmp \;` should do the trick. That doesn't explain why you are seeing a line feed hanging out there, but I'm betting it will resolve it.

Comment: Perfect, I learned something. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think the problem is that you use `xargs -0` (expects NUL byte separated arguments), but nowhere do you produce the NUL bytes (would have to be `find -print0` and `grep -z`). xargs effectively gets a single long string that includes linebreaks, hence the `\n` tar complains about.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JNevill, the command works and we can do all theses actions in find command

```
find -type f -name "*file_*" -exec tar -zxf {} --directory /tmp \;
```